# usize ownership issue with iterators

Tags: rust

The following code takes a `[[char; 10]; 3]` keyboard layout and returns the finger and finger movement required to press the key.

From my initial understanding of ownership and borrowing in Rust, I got the idea that the developer only has to worry about ownership of memory allocated on the heap. Primitives, on the other hand, will make a copy of themselves when necessary.

```rust
impl KeyboardBuilder {
    fn build(char_layout: [[char; 10]; 3]) -> HashMap<char, Key> {
        char_layout
            .iter()
            .enumerate()
            .map(|(y, row)| {
                row.iter().enumerate().map(|(x, char)| {
                    (char, Key::new(
                        char,
                        KeyboardBuilder::get_finger(x as u8),
                        KeyboardBuilder::get_pos(x as u8, y as u8),
                    ))
                })
            })
            .flatten()
            .collect()
    }
}
```

To correct the code, I have to change the ownership of the `char`, and use `move` to move the ownership.

```rust
char_layout
    .iter()
    .enumerate()
    .map(|(y, row)| {
        row.iter().enumerate().map(move |(x, char)| {
        //                         ^^^^
            (char.to_owned(), Key::new(
                // ^^^^^^^^^
                char.to_owned(),
                //   ^^^^^^^^^
                KeyboardBuilder::get_finger(x as u8),
                KeyboardBuilder::get_pos(x as u8, y as u8),
            ))
        })
    })
```

I have multiple questions,

- Why do I have to change the ownership of primitives? Why they do not create copies from iterator to iterator?
- What is the functionality and the difference between `move` and `to_owned()`?
- I have to use `to_owned()` in both `tupal` and `Key::new` parameter. Now who is the owner of the `char`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why do I have to change the ownership of primitives? Why they do not create copies from iterator to iterator?

This isn't an ownership issue, really; it's just a type mismatch. You don't have a primitive; you have a *reference* to a primitive, `&char` instead of `char`. This happens because whenever you iterate over a collection with `.iter()`, you get references to the items of the collection — even if they are simple primitives that would be better passed by value.

There are several fixes to this; you can write `*` to dereference:

```rust
    fn build(char_layout: [[char; 10]; 3]) -> HashMap<char, Key> {
        char_layout
            .iter()
            .enumerate()
            .map(|(y, row)| {
                row.iter().enumerate().map(|(x, char)| {
                    (*char, Key::new(...))
                })
            })
            .flatten()
            .collect()
    }
```

You can pattern match the reference:

```rust
    fn build(char_layout: [[char; 10]; 3]) -> HashMap<char, Key> {
        char_layout
            .iter()
            .enumerate()
            .map(|(y, row)| {
                row.iter().enumerate().map(|(x, &char)| {
                    (char, Key::new(...))
                })
            })
            .flatten()
            .collect()
    }
```

You can use `Iterator::copied`, which converts an iterator of references to an iterator of copies of their referents:

```rust
    fn build(char_layout: [[char; 10]; 3]) -> HashMap<char, Key> {
        char_layout
            .iter()
            .enumerate()
            .map(|(y, row)| {
                row.iter().copied().enumerate().map(|(x, char)| {
                    (char, Key::new(...))
                })
            })
            .flatten()
            .collect()
    }
```

Or, you can use `.to_owned()` as you discovered. All of these make a copy of the value behind the reference. Another option is to iterate over the array by-value (which consumes the array); this is unfortunately clunky due to some backwards-compatibility issues, but will hopefully be more convenient in future Rust versions.

```rust
use std::array::IntoIter;
...
    fn build(char_layout: [[char; 10]; 3]) -> HashMap<char, Key> {
        IntoIter::new(char_layout)
            .enumerate()
            .map(|(y, row)| {
                IntoIter::new(row).enumerate().map(|(x, char)| {
                    (char, Key::new(...))
                })
            })
            .flatten()
            .collect()
    }
```

> What is the functionality and the difference between `move` and `.to_owned()`?

`move` is unnecessary (but harmless) here. I suspect you added it in response to an unrelated error while you were experimenting. In general, `move` changes the way a closure (the anonymous functions you pass to `.map()`) captures variables from its environment, to move (or copy) them rather than taking references to them. This is not necessary for your situation because you are not *returning* a closure or doing anything else requiring a closure to outlive the function it was created in.

`.to_owned()` takes a reference to a value and constructs an 'owned' copy of that value; for primitives, it's just the same as dereferencing the reference. It's most commonly useful for `&str` references, where the owned value is a different type (`String`).

> I have to use `.to_owned()` in both tupal and `Key::new` parameter. Now who is the owner of the char?

The tuple and the `Key` own those *copies* of the character. `.to_owned()` doesn't *take* ownership; it makes a copy.